# Where the wrong in this sql?

Tags: sql

What's wrong in this cquery?

```
$cquery= mysqli_query ("SELECT R.cr_ id,R.time,R.reply FROM conversation_reply R WHERE R.c_id_fk='$c_id' ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 1;") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving space here

```
SELECT R.cr_ id,
            ^
          here
```

This space is this problem.

Try like this

```
SELECT R.cr_id,R.time,R.reply FROM conversation_reply R WHERE R.c_id_fk='$c_id' ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: are you from bangladesh?

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2013/05/message-conversation-database-design.html @GolokMallick

Comment: amar demo code gulo chai. But okhane demo nai. Just live demo option ase. Amar just conversation list code ta chai. Jekhane conversation list and conversation er last message thakbe.

Comment: oikhane concept deya hoise kivabe databse design korben coding korben .. direct code er asa korle to bhai kisu sikhte parben na .. jei concept dise seita follow koren .. apnar kaj hoye jabe ..